# Union/Merge 3D polygons (POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z) each with different heights to output a single polygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, merge, 3d, union

While attempting to ST_Union, ST_Collect, ST_3DUnion an array of POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z geometries with different heights, the output is always a multipolygon with interior walls.

I need to fully merge the geometries so that the result is a single polygon (polyhedral).

In one of the trial cases bellow, I am turning the geometry into individual triangles and regroup them to attempt to get the a polygon out of the result.
This is done because a simple ST_Collect results in a geometry collection, so you need to break it out then rebuild it.

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_AsText(ST_Collect(geom))) AS geom 
    FROM (
        SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_ExteriorRing(
            (ST_Dump(
                ST_Tesselate(

                    ST_Collect( 
                        ARRAY[
                            ST_SETSRID(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((-137 53.3675 25500,-135 52.71667 25500,-133.75 51 25500,-132.81833 50.60833 25500,-133.99022 50.59698 25500,-137 53.3675 25500)),((-137 53.3675 99999,-133.99022 50.59698 99999,-132.81833 50.60833 99999,-133.75 51 99999,-135 52.71667 99999,-137 53.3675 99999)),((-137 53.3675 25500,-137 53.3675 99999,-135 52.71667 99999,-135 52.71667 25500,-137 53.3675 25500)),((-135 52.71667 25500,-135 52.71667 99999,-133.75 51 99999,-133.75 51 25500,-135 52.71667 25500)),((-133.75 51 25500,-133.75 51 99999,-132.81833 50.60833 99999,-132.81833 50.60833 25500,-133.75 51 25500)),((-132.81833 50.60833 25500,-132.81833 50.60833 99999,-133.99022 50.59698 99999,-133.99022 50.59698 25500,-132.81833 50.60833 25500)),((-133.99022 50.59698 25500,-133.99022 50.59698 99999,-137 53.3675 99999,-137 53.3675 25500,-133.99022 50.59698 25500)))'), 4326),
                            ST_SETSRID(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((-135 52.71667 23000,-135.61667 53.5 23000,-133.5 53.25 23000,-132.91667 52.7 23000,-131.05528 51.54167 23000,-132.33833 50.63028 23000,-132.81833 50.60833 23000,-133.75 51 23000,-135 52.71667 23000)),((-135 52.71667 99999,-133.75 51 99999,-132.81833 50.60833 99999,-132.33833 50.63028 99999,-131.05528 51.54167 99999,-132.91667 52.7 99999,-133.5 53.25 99999,-135.61667 53.5 99999,-135 52.71667 99999)),((-135 52.71667 23000,-135 52.71667 99999,-135.61667 53.5 99999,-135.61667 53.5 23000,-135 52.71667 23000)),((-135.61667 53.5 23000,-135.61667 53.5 99999,-133.5 53.25 99999,-133.5 53.25 23000,-135.61667 53.5 23000)),((-133.5 53.25 23000,-133.5 53.25 99999,-132.91667 52.7 99999,-132.91667 52.7 23000,-133.5 53.25 23000)),((-132.91667 52.7 23000,-132.91667 52.7 99999,-131.05528 51.54167 99999,-131.05528 51.54167 23000,-132.91667 52.7 23000)),((-131.05528 51.54167 23000,-131.05528 51.54167 99999,-132.33833 50.63028 99999,-132.33833 50.63028 23000,-131.05528 51.54167 23000)),((-132.33833 50.63028 23000,-132.33833 50.63028 99999,-132.81833 50.60833 99999,-132.81833 50.60833 23000,-132.33833 50.63028 23000)),((-132.81833 50.60833 23000,-132.81833 50.60833 99999,-133.75 51 99999,-133.75 51 23000,-132.81833 50.60833 23000)),((-133.75 51 23000,-133.75 51 99999,-135 52.71667 99999,-135 52.71667 23000,-133.75 51 23000)))'), 4326),
                            ST_SETSRID(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((-135 52.71667 0,-137 53.3675 0,-136 54 0,-135.45 54.10833 0,-135.09111 54.11194 0,-133.5 53.25 0,-135.61667 53.5 0,-135 52.71667 0)),((-135 52.71667 99999,-135.61667 53.5 99999,-133.5 53.25 99999,-135.09111 54.11194 99999,-135.45 54.10833 99999,-136 54 99999,-137 53.3675 99999,-135 52.71667 99999)),((-135 52.71667 0,-135 52.71667 99999,-137 53.3675 99999,-137 53.3675 0,-135 52.71667 0)),((-137 53.3675 0,-137 53.3675 99999,-136 54 99999,-136 54 0,-137 53.3675 0)),((-136 54 0,-136 54 99999,-135.45 54.10833 99999,-135.45 54.10833 0,-136 54 0)),((-135.45 54.10833 0,-135.45 54.10833 99999,-135.09111 54.11194 99999,-135.09111 54.11194 0,-135.45 54.10833 0)),((-135.09111 54.11194 0,-135.09111 54.11194 99999,-133.5 53.25 99999,-133.5 53.25 0,-135.09111 54.11194 0)),((-133.5 53.25 0,-133.5 53.25 99999,-135.61667 53.5 99999,-135.61667 53.5 0,-133.5 53.25 0)),((-135.61667 53.5 0,-135.61667 53.5 99999,-135 52.71667 99999,-135 52.71667 0,-135.61667 53.5 0)))'), 4326)
                        ]
                    )
                )
            )).geom
        )) AS geom
) as geom_item;
```

[image: result of union polyhedral z]
[image: result of union polyhedral z]

I'm trying as many tricks as I can find or think but each output the same result and I feel that this might not be possible.
I looked into ST_ConcaveHull but I'm not sure that would for in my scenario.

Is it possible to merge multiple 3D geometries (polyhedralsurfacez) that have varying height and output as a single polygon (no interior walls)?

Or is this outside what is possible with postgis functions?

Comment: It might be, but it is very hard to tell from your example query. First of all, ST_3DUnion only works on two geometries at a time and, second, you are using 4326, but you have z values such as 25500. I think the z value should be in the same measurement system as your SRID.

Comment: Can you provide 2 geometries that demonstrate the behaviour you are referring to -- ie, interrior walls, after a union. If it is possible to get that working, then it is always possible to generalize to more than 2.

Comment: As far as I can tell, 4326 support height dimension
http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/

Comment: did you manage to do it?

Comment: Not with PostGIS. We redid the shape externally with thirdparty software and took the new model after.
Unfortunately this is some years ago so I cannot comment much more on the solution that was achieved.

Answer (score 2):

Simple attempt. 3D Union polyhedrons using ST_3DUnion.
ST_3DUnion outputs as TIN Z triangles, so you need to create a new geometry out of it to eventually output as geojson.

This is being output as a multipolygon.

SQL:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Collect(geom)) AS geom 
    FROM (
        SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_ExteriorRing(
            (ST_Dump(
                ST_3DUnion(
                    ST_SETSRID(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((-135 52.71667 23000,-135.61667 53.5 23000,-133.5 53.25 23000,-132.91667 52.7 23000,-131.05528 51.54167 23000,-132.33833 50.63028 23000,-132.81833 50.60833 23000,-133.75 51 23000,-135 52.71667 23000)),((-135 52.71667 99999,-133.75 51 99999,-132.81833 50.60833 99999,-132.33833 50.63028 99999,-131.05528 51.54167 99999,-132.91667 52.7 99999,-133.5 53.25 99999,-135.61667 53.5 99999,-135 52.71667 99999)),((-135 52.71667 23000,-135 52.71667 99999,-135.61667 53.5 99999,-135.61667 53.5 23000,-135 52.71667 23000)),((-135.61667 53.5 23000,-135.61667 53.5 99999,-133.5 53.25 99999,-133.5 53.25 23000,-135.61667 53.5 23000)),((-133.5 53.25 23000,-133.5 53.25 99999,-132.91667 52.7 99999,-132.91667 52.7 23000,-133.5 53.25 23000)),((-132.91667 52.7 23000,-132.91667 52.7 99999,-131.05528 51.54167 99999,-131.05528 51.54167 23000,-132.91667 52.7 23000)),((-131.05528 51.54167 23000,-131.05528 51.54167 99999,-132.33833 50.63028 99999,-132.33833 50.63028 23000,-131.05528 51.54167 23000)),((-132.33833 50.63028 23000,-132.33833 50.63028 99999,-132.81833 50.60833 99999,-132.81833 50.60833 23000,-132.33833 50.63028 23000)),((-132.81833 50.60833 23000,-132.81833 50.60833 99999,-133.75 51 99999,-133.75 51 23000,-132.81833 50.60833 23000)),((-133.75 51 23000,-133.75 51 99999,-135 52.71667 99999,-135 52.71667 23000,-133.75 51 23000)))'), 4979),
                    ST_SETSRID(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((-135 52.71667 0,-137 53.3675 0,-136 54 0,-135.45 54.10833 0,-135.09111 54.11194 0,-133.5 53.25 0,-135.61667 53.5 0,-135 52.71667 0)),((-135 52.71667 99999,-135.61667 53.5 99999,-133.5 53.25 99999,-135.09111 54.11194 99999,-135.45 54.10833 99999,-136 54 99999,-137 53.3675 99999,-135 52.71667 99999)),((-135 52.71667 0,-135 52.71667 99999,-137 53.3675 99999,-137 53.3675 0,-135 52.71667 0)),((-137 53.3675 0,-137 53.3675 99999,-136 54 99999,-136 54 0,-137 53.3675 0)),((-136 54 0,-136 54 99999,-135.45 54.10833 99999,-135.45 54.10833 0,-136 54 0)),((-135.45 54.10833 0,-135.45 54.10833 99999,-135.09111 54.11194 99999,-135.09111 54.11194 0,-135.45 54.10833 0)),((-135.09111 54.11194 0,-135.09111 54.11194 99999,-133.5 53.25 99999,-133.5 53.25 0,-135.09111 54.11194 0)),((-133.5 53.25 0,-133.5 53.25 99999,-135.61667 53.5 99999,-135.61667 53.5 0,-133.5 53.25 0)),((-135.61667 53.5 0,-135.61667 53.5 99999,-135 52.71667 99999,-135 52.71667 0,-135.61667 53.5 0)))'), 4979)
                )
            )).geom
        )) AS geom
    ) as geom_item;
```

[image]

Geojson:

```
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-135.141835518355,52.896837701677,23000],[-135.61667,53.5,23000],[-135.12983103161,53.4424994249943,23000],[-135.141835518355,52.896837701677,23000]]],[[[-135,52.71667,23000],[-135.141835518355,52.896837701677,23000],[-135.12983103161,53.4424994249943,23000],[-135,52.71667,23000]]],[[[-133.5,53.25,23000],[-135,52.71667,23000],[-135.12983103161,53.4424994249943,23000],[-133.5,53.25,23000]]],[[[-135.61667,53.5,99999],[-135,52.71667,99999],[-133.5,53.25,99999],[-135.61667,53.5,99999]]],[[[-135.348401582673,53.1592298971175,56496.6835839953],[-135,52.71667,99999],[-135.61667,53.5,99999],[-135.348401582673,53.1592298971175,56496.6835839953]]],[[[-135.61667,53.5,23000],[-135.348401582673,53.1592298971175,56496.6835839953],[-135.61667,53.5,99999],[-135.61667,53.5,23000]]],[[[-135.348401582673,53.1592298971175,56496.6835839953],[-135,52.71667,23000],[-135,52.71667,99999],[-135.348401582673,53.1592298971175,56496.6835839953]]],[[[-135.348401582673,53.1592298971175,56496.6835839953],[-135.141835518355,52.896837701677,23000],[-135,52.71667,23000],[-135.348401582673,53.1592298971175,56496.6835839953]]],[[[-135.61667,53.5,23000],[-135.141835518355,52.896837701677,23000],[-135.348401582673,53.1592298971175,56496.6835839953],[-135.61667,53.5,23000]]],[[[-134.42080968898,53.3587568786088,56496.6835839953],[-135.61667,53.5,99999],[-133.5,53.25,99999],[-134.42080968898,53.3587568786088,56496.6835839953]]],[[[-133.5,53.25,23000],[-134.42080968898,53.3587568786088,56496.6835839953],[-133.5,53.25,99999],[-133.5,53.25,23000]]],[[[-134.42080968898,53.3587568786088,56496.6835839953],[-135.61667,53.5,23000],[-135.61667,53.5,99999],[-134.42080968898,53.3587568786088,56496.6835839953]]],[[[-134.42080968898,53.3587568786088,56496.6835839953],[-135.12983103161,53.4424994249943,23000],[-135.61667,53.5,23000],[-134.42080968898,53.3587568786088,56496.6835839953]]],[[[-133.5,53.25,23000],[-135.12983103161,53.4424994249943,23000],[-134.42080968898,53.3587568786088,56496.6835839953],[-133.5,53.25,23000]]],[[[-132.91667,52.7,23000],[-135,52.71667,23000],[-133.5,53.25,23000],[-132.91667,52.7,23000]]],[[[-133.75,51,23000],[-135,52.71667,23000],[-132.91667,52.7,23000],[-133.75,51,23000]]],[[[-132.91667,52.7,99999],[-135,52.71667,99999],[-133.75,51,99999],[-132.91667,52.7,99999]]],[[[-133.5,53.25,99999],[-135,52.71667,99999],[-132.91667,52.7,99999],[-133.5,53.25,99999]]],[[[-135,52.71667,23000],[-133.75,51,99999],[-135,52.71667,99999],[-135,52.71667,23000]]],[[[-135,52.71667,23000],[-133.75,51,23000],[-133.75,51,99999],[-135,52.71667,23000]]],[[[-132.81833,50.60833,23000],[-133.75,51,23000],[-132.91667,52.7,23000],[-132.81833,50.60833,23000]]],[[[-132.81833,50.60833,99999],[-132.91667,52.7,99999],[-133.75,51,99999],[-132.81833,50.60833,99999]]],[[[-133.75,51,23000],[-132.81833,50.60833,99999],[-133.75,51,99999],[-133.75,51,23000]]],[[[-133.75,51,23000],[-132.81833,50.60833,23000],[-132.81833,50.60833,99999],[-133.75,51,23000]]],[[[-132.91667,52.7,23000],[-133.5,53.25,99999],[-132.91667,52.7,99999],[-132.91667,52.7,23000]]],[[[-132.91667,52.7,23000],[-133.5,53.25,23000],[-133.5,53.25,99999],[-132.91667,52.7,23000]]],[[[-131.05528,51.54167,23000],[-132.33833,50.63028,23000],[-132.91667,52.7,23000],[-131.05528,51.54167,23000]]],[[[-132.33833,50.63028,23000],[-132.81833,50.60833,23000],[-132.91667,52.7,23000],[-132.33833,50.63028,23000]]],[[[-132.33833,50.63028,99999],[-132.91667,52.7,99999],[-132.81833,50.60833,99999],[-132.33833,50.63028,99999]]],[[[-132.33833,50.63028,99999],[-131.05528,51.54167,99999],[-132.91667,52.7,99999],[-132.33833,50.63028,99999]]],[[[-131.05528,51.54167,23000],[-132.91667,52.7,99999],[-131.05528,51.54167,99999],[-131.05528,51.54167,23000]]],[[[-131.05528,51.54167,23000],[-132.91667,52.7,23000],[-132.91667,52.7,99999],[-131.05528,51.54167,23000]]],[[[-132.81833,50.60833,23000],[-132.33833,50.63028,99999],[-132.81833,50.60833,99999],[-132.81833,50.60833,23000]]],[[[-132.81833,50.60833,23000],[-132.33833,50.63028,23000],[-132.33833,50.63028,99999],[-132.81833,50.60833,23000]]],[[[-132.33833,50.63028,23000],[-131.05528,51.54167,99999],[-132.33833,50.63028,99999],[-132.33833,50.63028,23000]]],[[[-132.33833,50.63028,23000],[-131.05528,51.54167,23000],[-131.05528,51.54167,99999],[-132.33833,50.63028,23000]]],[[[-135.61667,53.5,0],[-137,53.3675,0],[-136,54,0],[-135.61667,53.5,0]]],[[[-135,52.71667,0],[-137,53.3675,0],[-135.61667,53.5,0],[-135,52.71667,0]]],[[[-135,52.71667,99999],[-135.61667,53.5,99999],[-137,53.3675,99999],[-135,52.71667,99999]]],[[[-137,53.3675,99999],[-135.61667,53.5,99999],[-136,54,99999],[-137,53.3675,99999]]],[[[-137,53.3675,0],[-135,52.71667,99999],[-137,53.3675,99999],[-137,53.3675,0]]],[[[-137,53.3675,0],[-135,52.71667,0],[-135,52.71667,23000],[-137,53.3675,0]]],[[[-135,52.71667,99999],[-137,53.3675,0],[-135,52.71667,23000],[-135,52.71667,99999]]],[[[-136,54,0],[-137,53.3675,99999],[-136,54,99999],[-136,54,0]]],[[[-136,54,0],[-137,53.3675,0],[-137,53.3675,99999],[-136,54,0]]],[[[-135.45,54.10833,0],[-135.61667,53.5,0],[-136,54,0],[-135.45,54.10833,0]]],[[[-136,54,99999],[-135.61667,53.5,99999],[-135.45,54.10833,99999],[-136,54,99999]]],[[[-135.45,54.10833,0],[-136,54,99999],[-135.45,54.10833,99999],[-135.45,54.10833,0]]],[[[-135.45,54.10833,0],[-136,54,0],[-136,54,99999],[-135.45,54.10833,0]]],[[[-135.45,54.10833,0],[-135.09111,54.11194,0],[-135.61667,53.5,0],[-135.45,54.10833,0]]],[[[-133.5,53.25,0],[-135.61667,53.5,0],[-135.09111,54.11194,0],[-133.5,53.25,0]]],[[[-135.09111,54.11194,99999],[-135.61667,53.5,99999],[-133.5,53.25,99999],[-135.09111,54.11194,99999]]],[[[-135.45,54.10833,99999],[-135.61667,53.5,99999],[-135.09111,54.11194,99999],[-135.45,54.10833,99999]]],[[[-135.61667,53.5,0],[-135.12983103161,53.4424994249943,23000],[-135.61667,53.5,23000],[-135.61667,53.5,0]]],[[[-135.12983103161,53.4424994249943,23000],[-133.5,53.25,0],[-133.5,53.25,23000],[-135.12983103161,53.4424994249943,23000]]],[[[-135.12983103161,53.4424994249943,23000],[-135.61667,53.5,0],[-133.5,53.25,0],[-135.12983103161,53.4424994249943,23000]]],[[[-135,52.71667,0],[-135.141835518355,52.896837701677,23000],[-135,52.71667,23000],[-135,52.71667,0]]],[[[-135.141835518355,52.896837701677,23000],[-135.61667,53.5,0],[-135.61667,53.5,23000],[-135.141835518355,52.896837701677,23000]]],[[[-135.141835518355,52.896837701677,23000],[-135,52.71667,0],[-135.61667,53.5,0],[-135.141835518355,52.896837701677,23000]]],[[[-135.09111,54.11194,0],[-135.45,54.10833,99999],[-135.09111,54.11194,99999],[-135.09111,54.11194,0]]],[[[-135.09111,54.11194,0],[-135.45,54.10833,0],[-135.45,54.10833,99999],[-135.09111,54.11194,0]]],[[[-133.5,53.25,23000],[-135.09111,54.11194,99999],[-133.5,53.25,99999],[-133.5,53.25,23000]]],[[[-133.5,53.25,0],[-135.09111,54.11194,99999],[-133.5,53.25,23000],[-133.5,53.25,0]]],[[[-133.5,53.25,0],[-135.09111,54.11194,0],[-135.09111,54.11194,99999],[-133.5,53.25,0]]]]}
```

In the image, you can see all the individual polygons randomly colored.

The problem seems that trying to make a polygon out of the individual triangles only results in them all being triangles.

Comment: I get errors if I just run the ST_3DUnion part of this, without all the geosjon, exteriorring, dump stuff: `NOTICE:  During union_3d(A,B) :
ERROR:  TriangulatedSurface is invalid : inconsistent orientation of PolyhedralSurface detected at edge 2 (7-4) of polygon 61 `. My guess is that you have to set the right hand rule correctly, first.

Comment: Hmm, thats seems strange. 
If I simply run only the `ST_3DUnion` for the two geometries it returns a TIN Z geometry

Comment: I may have a different version of Postgis, sfgcal, linux, etc :-). I am just starting to use the 3D functionality in anger, and while it seems very powerful, I am getting some interesting errors every now and then. Cool image, btw, what did you use to generate it: ST_AsX3D?

Comment: Using Postgis 2.3.0 with sfgcal. I think having the latest will help.
The geojson generated is loaded into [CesiumJS](https://cesiumjs.org/) which is what you're seeing in the images.
Its open source geospatial 3D mapping in javascript.

Comment: I have 2.3.3. Yes, I am familiar with CesiumJS, from my OpenLayers 3 days. I was going to test ST_AsX3D, but I prefer using JSON, so I might try your approach. Nevertheless, I still get the same error messages as above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that error is coming from SFCGAL. @JohnPowellakaBarça: could you check your SFCGAL version?

Comment: SFCGAL version 1.2.2. My full postgis version is POSTGIS="2.3.3 r15473" GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246" SFCGAL="1.2.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16" LIBXML="2.9.3" LIBJSON="0.11.99" RASTER